Set Ununtu time using web server
I am using nanopi board/ Ubuntu TLS 20.04 focal
have a simpoole site using nginx web server
inside a the page there is a button to apply new time to the system using "exec(date --set='')"
I have tried all possible configuration to setup using sudo and even add www-data ALL:nonpassword to visudo
then grant folder /var/www/html access www-data:www-data
and permission 777
but I cannot modfiy the system time or restart it using my website
even I can do thesse operations using command promot.
please help.!

date --set requires superuser privileges, so you have to use sudo. Probably you used wrong syntax either in your exec command on the webpage or in the sudoers file. Have you checked your webserver logs? Error messages should be there...

I have used sudo without result

Look in the logs, as I have written. If anything goes wrong, that's the first place to check. Nobody can help you without detailed information, and that information is in the logs.
